# Быстрое считывание с++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с написанием быстрого считывания из файла с помощью getchar_unlock(). В файле есть две строки не обязательно одинакового размера, сколько символов в каждой строке тоже не известно, нужно считать их в 2 массива или вектора, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Проблема: код считывает только 1 число, не знаю как сделать для всей строки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool read_int_unlocked(int & out)
{
    int c = getchar_unlocked();
    int x = 0;
    int neg = 0;

    for (; !('0'<=c && c<='9') && c != '-'; c = getchar_unlocked())
    {
        if (c == EOF)
            return false;
    }
    if (c == '-')
    {
        neg = 1;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    if (c == EOF)
        return false;
    for (; '0' <= c && c <= '9' ; c = getchar_unlocked())
    {
        x = x*10 + c - '0';
    }
    out = neg ? -x : x;
    return true;
}

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int number;

    while(read_int_unlocked(number))
        std::cout << number << " ";   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Гляньте на инструкцию как задавать вопросы (ссылка на нее есть на форме для редактирования вопросов)

Comment: Покажите свое решение, и опишите, что именно у вас не получается. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ваши плюсы, больно на си походят

Answer (score 0):

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int read_int_unlocked(int & out)
{
    int c = getchar_unlocked();
    int x = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    
    for (; !('0'<=c && c<='9') && c != '-'; c = getchar_unlocked())
    {
        if (c == EOF)
            return 0;
    }
    if (c == '-')
    {
        neg = 1;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    if (c == EOF)
        return 0;
    for (; '0' <= c && c <= '9' ; c = getchar_unlocked())
    {
        x = x*10 + c - '0';
    }
    
    out = neg ? -x : x;
    if(c == '\n') return 2;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    
    int number;
    int oldVec = 1;
    bool cycle = true;
    while(cycle){
        int res = read_int_unlocked(number);
        if(res == 0) cycle = false;
        if(res == 1) {
            if(oldVec) v1.push_back(number);
            else v2.push_back(number);
        }
        if(res == 2) {
            if(oldVec) v1.push_back(number);
            else v2.push_back(number);
            oldVec = false;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) std::cout << v1[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++) std::cout << v2[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```